# Trying to import winsound

Tags: python-3.x, import

When I import winsound and then try to run the program, it returns an error message saying:

`ImportError: No module named 'winsound'.`

Are there any settings I need to change?

Answer (score 3):

`winsound` only exists in Python installed under Windows. Do not attempt to import it if you are not running under Windows.